# While using GetMaterialApp fontFamily for the Theme is not Changing

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, flutter-theme, flutter-material

I am using Getx for my state management. So When I Change MaterialApp to GetMaterialApp, the fontFamily switched back to the default.

pubspec.yaml file

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  fonts:
    - family: Sen
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Sen-Regular.ttf
          weight: 300
        - asset: assets/fonts/Sen-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

and I have saved Sen.ttf files in the assets/fonts folder
[image]

main.dart

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
        primary: kPrimaryColor,
        secondary: kSecondaryColor,
       ),
      fontFamily: "Sen"
      )
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const MainScreen(),
    );
  }
```

If I switch back to MaterialApp font will work fine.
Any help will be appreciated, Thank You.

Comment: Removing the leading `assets` folder might help: `- asset: fonts/Sen-Bold.ttf`

Comment: Tried but not helping

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem, but everything for fine for me with `GetMaterialApp` and `fontFamily`. The only difference is that I use ` getPages:` instead of `home:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once this happened to me while working with some google fonts.
I tried different methods, there is nothing wrong with **GetMaterialApp()**
**Option 1**:
`flutter clean` to clear all data, then update all the packages, and then `flutter pub get`
**Option 2**:
Initialy this is what I did. In the *textTheme*, add `TextStyle` for different types of text (headline1,bodyText1,etc)

```
fontFamily: "Sen",
textTheme: const TextTheme(
   headline1: TextStyle(
     fontSize: 96.0,
     fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
     fontFamily: 'Sen',
     color: kPrimaryTextColor,
   )
```

**Option 3**:
If nothing works, try `flutter upgrade`

Comment: The second method worked for me thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using the minimal code but everything works for me. The font changes as you can see in the [VIDEO DEMO](https://youtu.be/MOQcBll--Tw). I suggest you to clean the cache or update the packages version to latest

Example

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      initialRoute: RoutesName.homePage,
      getPages: Routes.getPages(),
      initialBinding: InitialBindings(),
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: "Blaka"),
    );
  }
```

pubspec file

```
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

  fonts: 
    - family: Blaka
      fonts: 
        - asset: assets/fonts/Blaka/Blaka-Regular.ttf
```

Comment: Really appreciate the effort you put into this, thank you. I will try and update

Answer (score 0):

I had to move the fonts directory into the top-level directory so the path for the fonts in the pubspect.yaml file would be.

```
fonts/
```

instead of

```
assets/fonts
```

(I also had to correct the indentation in the pubspec)